# Popup topmost only outlook window

Tags: wpf, user-controls, popup, outlook-addin

I have created a Outlook Addin Project and I used WPF user control as element host in UserControl(WinForm) which is loaded using Custom Task Pane.

I have some dragoperation in wpf usercontrol which will open Popup.

The problem is the popup is showing topmost window for all the windows.

I need to show/visible only when outlook window activated. Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your popup is a child of the appropriate Outlook window. You cast Outlook Inspector or Explorer object to IOleWindow interface and call IOleWindow.GetWindow to retrieve HWND. You can then use WindowInteropHelper class along with the retrieved HWND to display your window.